# Which order should I use?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, atoms

I was working on hydrogen-deuterium mass ratio and I'm having a bit of confusion. When calculating the wavelength using this equation $$\frac{1}{\lambda}=R_H\left(\frac{1}{n_f^2}-\frac{1}{n_i^2}\right)$$ I'm not sure which principal quantum number I should use. In the experiment, the H-D source was emitting a purple color so I know that the electron must be transitioning from a very high state to $n=2$. But I was told that I was using a color filter (which made the H-D source look red). Does this affect what value I should use for $n$? Because then the electron would be transitioning from 3 to 2.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Of course not. Unless there is something I don't know in  the world of particle physics.

Comment: I think I completely misinterpreted the word “order” in your title….   I will remove my previous comment and this one soon after.

Comment: One thing I could think of is that your source is emitting a spectrum of lines, and the color filter is removing high frequency / small wavelength "blue" lines, so that the line(s) you actually observe are only the relatively low frequency / large wavelength "red" ones.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, your second comment is what describes what happened in the experiment. My question is, do I have to take my $n_f$  to be very high because that is the only way I could minimize the wavelength so that it agrees with what I saw(which was a light source of purple/violet color) or am I looking at it wrong?

Comment: Well, according to your question, $n_f=2$ right? (Actually, why not $n_f=1$?) There are a couple of things you can do to get a handle on $n_i$. First, since you observed purple, you can convert purple to a range of wavelengths that you might have seen. What range of $n_i$ does that correspond to? Second, if I've understood your setup, knowing what frequencies your filter blocks should give you a minimum wavelength you are able to observe. How does that bound $n_i$?